# Java Animation Rotation

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have very little experience with Java, and I am an amateur programmer. So mind my vocabulary.

I want to be able to stick a static rectangle on top of a rotating rectangle.
So far when I try to add another object it spins with the other image. I have tried setting the rotation to zero but that doesn't seem to work. I have also tried to create another class that draws components separately and added them to the frame using frame.add. I have also tried creating another part to the Draw class that has no effect on the GUI. Here is my current Draw class. Any help is appreciated.

```
class DrawRectangle extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int h = this.getHeight();
        int w = this.getWidth();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        //draw background
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

        //draw roatiing rectangle
        g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        Rectangle rRec = new Rectangle(w / 4, h / 4, 2 * w / 4, 2 * h / 4);
        double wr = rRec.getX() + rRec.getWidth() / 2;
        double hr = rRec.getY() + rRec.getHeight() / 2;
        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(count), wr, hr);
        g2.fill(rRec);
        g2.fillRect(w / 3, h / 3, 2 * w / 3, 2 * h / 3);
    }

    public void paintComponent2(Graphics g) {
        int h = this.getHeight();
        int w = this.getWidth();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    }
}
```

Comment: The answers are correct, but please note that you can also reset the rotation by initially getting the old transform (`AffineTransform old = g2.getTransform();`) and then reseting it. (`g2.setTransform(old);`); - This will be useful in later projects, but it's not needed in this case.

Comment: Btw, don't forget to call `super.paintComponent(g)`.

Answer (score 3):

> So far when I try to add another object it spins with the other image.

Create a separate Graphics object to do the rotation so you don't affect the properties of the Graphics object passed into the painting method:

```
//Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();

//  painting code

g2.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your `g2.fill(rRec);` BEFORE the `rotate` call, and it should work (I just tested it out).

This way, you will draw your static rectangle before the rotation, perform the rotation, THEN draw your second rectangle. Assuming your `count` variable is incremented somewhere, it should show the second rectangle being rotated.